# Google maps iframe zooming is not work

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

i have a problem with Google maps iframe on my website 
when i use iframe form Google maps website and put zoom  not work

```
iframe src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zCqArMwLBI1M.kOBWLJlkdlWY&zoom=21" width="640" height="250"></iframe>
```

can any one help me
thanks

Comment: It works.. http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/e9fdgfpn/

Comment: work without zooming try to change the zoom number nothing will be

Comment: It works fine for me Amr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `z=` instead of `zoom=`

```
<iframe src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zCqArMwLBI1M.kOBWLJlkdlWY&z=15" width="640" height="250"></iframe>
```

The zoom level must be (1-20)

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/e9fdgfpn/1/)

Edit - 22nd April 2017

As per Connor William's comment

Google has updated its API use ZOOM instead Z=

Comment: @AmrEzz Happy to Help you ^_^

Comment: I'm not sure if somethings changed since this reply, but using `z` gives an `Unexpected parameter 'z'.` error, while `zoom` works.

Comment: The api has changed - you have to use "zoom" again.